# JAVA - reading from a file and writing to another

Tags: java, file, io

This is my code, I can't make it work properly, it gets just the last line from 3 lines total from the first text file and capitalize only that, and I cant figure out why

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.io.*;


    public class AllCapitals {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String readLine;

        String inFilePath = "/home/file.txt"; 
        String outFilePath = "/home/newFile.txt";


        try (BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inFilePath))) {

        while ((readLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            readLine.toUpperCase();
            String upperC = readLine.toUpperCase();

            System.out.println(upperC);

            try (Writer writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                    new FileOutputStream(outFilePath), "utf-8"))) {
                    writer.write(upperC);
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: Forgot to say the functionallity.

I need to read 3 lines from a normal text file that goes like that

```
    Hello.
    How are you ?
    Good, thank you !
```

And the output should be in all CAPS, but I get only the last line "GOOD THANK YOU"

Answer (score 3):

That's because you recreate the output file in each iteration while reading lines from the first.
Create the output file once before you start reading, for example:

```
    try (BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inFilePath));
         Writer writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(outFilePath), "utf-8"))
    ) {
        while ((readLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            String upperC = readLine.toUpperCase();
            System.out.println(upperC);

            writer.write(upperC);
            writer.write(System.lineSeparator());
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Some other improvements:

- Removed a pointless line `readLine.toUpperCase();` that did nothing
- Add a linebreak for each line, otherwise all the uppercased content would be on the same line